Importing file is resetting main bone position and changing scale on all bones
I have a blender model which has the MAIN bone as set to be pointing up in the +Z direction and I export this file as a .glb. When I import the model into a new blender file, the main bone is imported incorrectly in the flat position pointing in the +Y direction an it's is scaled large in size. All of the child bones are scaled down in size, but ARE oriented properly as they were in the original blender file. I have to then manually rotate the orientation of the MAIN bone and scale it down, then manually scale up the child bones. Is there some setting I need to change in order to have the imported .glb come in exaclty as it's original Blender file that it was exported from? Thanks for your help.
